# Displaying null balues at the end for more than one columns specified in order by clause

Tags: sql, firebird

I am using Firebird database. I have one issue in an `order by` clause.

I have SQL which gives multiple records for multiple employees, i.e. one employee has multiple records as an output in SQL.

I have four columns in an order by clause and I want every columns null value to be displayed after non-null value in every column.

I googled and found that if I use

```
Order By Column1 Asc Nulls Last
```

It works very well for the first columns but for the remaining two columns it doesn't work. For example for these two remaining columns the null value comes in middle, i.e. first some non-null values, then null values and then again non-null Values.

I need to display null Values at the end of every non-null value for every Four columns specified in the order by clause for every employee.

I tried `case when`, then `asc` for every column in order by clause, but that didn't give the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to add a column in the select clause :

```
case 
  when Column1 is not null
   and Column2 is not  null 
   and Column3 is not  null 
   and Column4 is not  null 
     then 0 else 1 
end as scol
```

and "scol" first in order by :

```
Order By scol, Column1 Asc Nulls Last, Column2 Asc Nulls Last, Column3 Asc Nulls Last, Column4 Asc Nulls Last
```

Rows with all 4 fields not null come first

Comment: You Are A Genius !!!!!!!!! Worked Perfectly As I Wanted... Many Many Thanks. But one thing I wrote wrongly in my previous post. The Null values I was getting as a result of my SQL. Sorry about that, but today I was about to correct it when I got your GENIUS Responce... Many Many Thanks :) !!!!!!!!